# Java dxa-example-webapp fails with Nullpointer exception

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

We are trying to install DXA 1.2 for Java on Weblogic following the instruction [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v2&lang=en-US). We have the following in cd_dynamic_conf.xml

```
<Publication Id="8">
  <Host Domain="localhost" Port="7001" Protocol="http" Path="/"/>
</Publication>
```

Our cd_storage_conf.xml points to the DB for all Item types, and I have verified that the page and binary contents are in the DB.

Here is the exception in the logs

> 11:35:21.271 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] TRACE c.sdl.webapp.tridion.DefaultProvider - getStaticContent: /system/config/_all.json [8] /
>   11:35:21.286 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /index.html
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at java.io.File.(File.java:277) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.DefaultProvider.getStaticContentFile(DefaultProvider.java:291) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.DefaultProvider.getStaticContent(DefaultProvider.java:260) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.parseJsonFileTree(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:190) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadMainConfiguration(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:110) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:86) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:88) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:57) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.LocalizationResolverInterceptor.preHandle(LocalizationResolverInterceptor.java:66) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AmbientDataServletFilter.java:302) [cd_ambient-7.1.0.jar:na]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AmbientDataServletFilter.java:302) [cd_ambient-7.1.0.jar:na]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]

Comment: Sounds like an issue serializing that page to the file system. Maybe your WebLogic user can't write to disk?

Comment: Why is it serializing to file system? Where is it trying to serialize it to and is that configurable? Is it possible to avoid serializing to disk?

Comment: Most app servers cannot deal with pages being served from a DB. DXA and other DD4T based solutions create files temporarily in File System. It's probably worth asking these questions in a separate question.